# Could I build an IVR or chat bot for iOS that interacted with _actual_ incoming phone calls?

Tags: ios

It looks to me from my reading through the various framework docs that it's possible to:

1. programmatically answer a call (I think).
2. treat the active call as an audio output device.

** but **

3. not receive input (audio or touchtone, I suppose) from the active call.

My questions, please:

- Is that more or less correct?
- If not, how does one receive input from the active call, ideally treating it as an audio source?
- If it is correct, how do the various call recording apps in the App Store make this work?

I've been over the docs for everything I could find on this, and even explored a few repos on GitHub that seemed related. No luck so far.

Comment: No, points 1 and 2 are not possible with the in-built cellular service. If your app is a voip client then you may be able to do it for calls to the voip number, but it would be easier to do it on the voip server